# Motivation behind a result of Munshi on nonvanishing of L-functions in families of elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, l-functions

In [this article](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=2771124) in Compositio (2011), Munshi proves a mean value result for
$$ \sum_{d} r(d) \Lambda^{(l)}(1/2,f,\chi_d) F(d/Y),$$
where here $f$ is a primitive holomorphic form of level $q$ with trivial nebentypus, the sum runs over fundamental discriminants coprime to $2q$, $\chi_d$ is the quadratic character for the fundamental discriminant $d$, $\Lambda(s,f,\chi_d)$ is the completed $L$-function for $f \otimes \chi_d$ (normalized to have critical line $\Re(s) = 1/2$), and $r(d)$ is the number of ways to write $d$ as a sum of two squares. Of course, $F$ is a compactly supported weight function.

Munshi provides some algebraic motivation for looking at this problem in his introduction which I don't exactly follow; he mentions that if $f$ is a modular form associated to an elliptic curve $E$, then the family $f \otimes \chi_d$ as $d$ runs over sums of two squares is connected to "quadratic elliptic fibrations" of $E$.

In any case, Munshi proves an asymptotic for $l \geqslant 8$, and uses this to conclude that for $l\geqslant 8$, $\Lambda^{(l)}(1/2,f,\chi_d)$ does not vanish for infinitely many $d$ such that $d$ is the sum of two squares -- the goal would ideally be to achieve $l = 0$, since then one is able to prove nonvanishing of the $L$-function itself, and it's easy enough to motivate this problem (especially since sums of two squares form a sparse subset of the integers).

Having said that, I would like to understand why Munshi weights the sum by $r(d)$ instead of the indicator function $\mathbf{1}_{\square+\square}(d)$ of sums of two squares. One answer might be that $r(d)$ is analytically a more natural weight to consider, since one can exploit the modularity of $r(d)$ (e.g., by applying Voronoi, or by opening $r(d)$ as a convolution and applying Poisson in one of the variables). Certainly, it is likely the case that computing an asymptotic would be harder with the weight $\mathbf{1}_{\square+\square}(d)$.

So here's the question: is there an algebraic reason for using this weight? Or is the reason to do so analytic convenience?